# SignalR-managing online and offline users

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to implement showing online and offline users using SignalR.
I have created a hub and implemented onConnected() method to call the function on client to show newly connected user to hub and onDisconnected() method to call the function on client to remove the disconnected user.I am using table and adding a new row if a new user is connected to the hub but not able to remove if a user disconnects from the hub.To remove the user disconnected, I am searching the table for that user and deleting the row but its not working.
This is what i have implemented so far:
onConnected() and Disconnected() methods on hub-

```
public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            var user = Users.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new User
            {
                username=userName,
                connectionIds=new HashSet<string>()
            });
            lock(user.connectionIds)
            {
                user.connectionIds.Add(connectionId);
                Clients.Others.userConnected(userName);
            }
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            User user;
            Users.TryGetValue(userName, out user);
            if (user != null)
            {
                lock (user.connectionIds)
                {
                    user.connectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));
                    if (!user.connectionIds.Any())
                    {
                        User removedUser;
                        Users.TryRemove(userName, out removedUser);
                        Clients.Others.userDisconnected(userName);
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
```

and javascript that i have implemented to add user to the table-

```
shapeMoveHub.client.userConnected = function (userName) {
            $("table").append("<tr><td>" + userName + "</td></tr>");
        };

        shapeMoveHub.client.userDisconnected = function (userName) {
            for(var row=0;row<$("table").rows.length;row++)
            {
                var rowData='';
                for(var col=0;col<$("table").rows[row].cells.length;col++)
                {
                     rowData = $("table").rows[row].cells[col].innerHTML;
                }
                if (rowData.indexOf(userName))
                    $("table").deleteRow(row);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Is it a SignalR-related problem? Or just a Javascript issue with your removal code? If you put a breakpoint in your `userDisconnected` handler, does it get hit? Same for your `OnDisconnected` event, did you check if it's triggered normally?

Comment: It's javascript issue. Its working fine if two users are connected to the hub, showing the connected users in table format but if three or more users are connected it's start showing in ',' separated manner.